# Пытаюсь создать базу данных. Этот модуль должен добавлять объекты

Tags: c

Я не понимаю, что не нравится моему компилятору. По синтаксису вроде бы все правильно. Помогите пожалуйста мне, бездарному человеку, найти в чем ошибка. Заголовочный файл такой:

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
int add(int &num, struct system *base);

#endif
```

---

```
#include "add.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int add(int &num, struct system *base) 
{
    int new = num;
    printf("Номер видеокасеты: ");
    scanf("%d", &base[num].number);
    printf("Название фильма: ");
    scanf("%s", base[num].name);
    printf("Страна, где был снят фильм: ");
    scanf("%s", base[num].country);
    printf("Продолжительность фильма: ");
    scanf("%d", &base[num].span);
    printf("Жанр фильма; ");
    scanf("%s", base[num].genre);
    printf("Дата приобретения касеты(через пробел): ");
    printf("День Месяц Год");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &base[num].day, &base[num].mounth, &base[num].year);
    num++;
    if(num == new + 1)
        printf("\nOK!\n");
    else
        printf("\nError\n");
    return new;
}
```

---

```
int main()
{
    struct system base[100];
    int num = 0;
    char name_file[40] = "export.txt";
    name_file;
    int key = 0;
    while (1) {
        key = menu();
        switch (key)
        {
            case 1:
                add(num, base);
                break;
            case 2:
                clear(num, base);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error! \n");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Выводит по ошибке в этих 2-х модулях.

clear.h

```
#ifndef CLEAR_H
#define CLEAR_H
int clear(int *num, system *base );
#endif
```

add.h

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
int add(int *num, system *base );
#endif
```

Осталось еще 2 ошибки...

```
cd '/Users/gorbunov/Downloads/Программы/my_kursach'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/my_kursach
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.c
In file included from main.c:3:
./add.h:3:19: error: unknown type name 'system'
int add(int *num, system *base);
                  ^
In file included from main.c:4:
./clear.h:3:21: error: unknown type name 'system'
int clear(int *num, system *base );
                    ^
main.c:11:5: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    name_file;
    ^~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

СОБРАТЬ FAILED (значение выхода 2,, общее время: 375ms)
```

Comment: Добавте код вместо картинки и  поправте формат.

Comment: Вот так пойдет?

Comment: @0xdb, о-па, а почему меня не предупредило о наличии правки в очереди, когда я внёс свою?

Comment: Судя по тому что вы передаете аргумент по ссылке, вы используете компилятор C++. Но в языке C++ слово `new` является ключевым. Возможно в этом проблема.

Comment: Сообщения об ошиках бы тоже добавили

Comment: @Arhad Чего не знаю, того не знаю. Владислав,  добавьте сообщение об ошибке и строку команды компилятора.

Comment: Вот, что выводит в терминале
Добавил скриншот

Comment: @Владислав покажите первые ошибки

Comment: @pank, смотрите

Comment: @Владислав Если вы на си пишете, то что означает - `int &num`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор у вас ругается (это же C) на передачу аргумента по ссылке

```
int add(int &num, struct system *base)
            ^ - вот этого C не умеет
```

Нужно так:

```
int add(int *num, struct system *base) 
{
    int new = *num;
    printf("Номер видеокасеты: ");
    scanf("%d", &base[new].number);
    ...
    (*num)++;
    ...
```

**Update**

Смотрите, в `main.h` сделайте так:

```
typedef struct system_{
    char name[50];
    char country[50];
    char genre[50];
    int span;
    int day;
    int number;
    int mounth;
    int year;
} system;
```

а в `add.c` -

```
int add(int *num, system *base)
{
    int mem = *num;
    printf("Номер видеокасеты: ");
    scanf("%d", &base[*num].number);
    printf("Название фильма: ");
    scanf("%s", base[*num].name);
    printf("Страна, где был снят фильм: ");
    scanf("%s", base[*num].country);
    printf("Продолжительность фильма: ");
    scanf("%d", &base[*num].span);
    printf("Жанр фильма; ");
    scanf("%s", base[*num].genre);
    printf("Дата приобретения касеты(через пробел): ");
    printf("День Месяц Год");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &base[*num].day, &base[*num].mounth, &base[*num].year);
    (*num)++;
    if(*num == mem + 1)
        printf("\nOK!\n");
    else
        printf("\nError\n");
    return mem;
}
```

Или объедините все h-файлы в один, или везде первым включайте `main.h` - ведь тип структуры объявляется в ней!

`clear.c` должен иметь вид

```
#include "main.h"
#include "clear.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int clear(int *num, system *base )
{
    char name[50];
    printf("Введите номер видеоксеты: ");
    scanf("%d", name);
    int sur = *num;
    for(int i=0; i<*num; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name, base[i].number)==0)
        {
            for(int j = i; j< *num - 1; j++)
            {
                strcpy(base[j].number, base[j+1].number);
                strcpy(base[j].name, base[j+1].name);
                strcpy(base[j].country, base[j+1].country);
                strcpy(base[j].genre, base[j+1].genre);
                strcpy(base[j].span, base[j+1].span);
                base[j].day = base[j+1].day;
                base[j].mounth = base[j+1].mounth;
                base[j].year = base[j+1].year;
            }
            (*num)--;
            if(*num == sur - 1)
                printf("OK!\n");
            else
                printf("Error!\n");
        }
    }
    return *num;
}
```

В `menu.c` уберите угловые скобки во включении `menu.h`, замените на кавычки, и включите `stdio.h`

`main.c` должна выглядеть как

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "menu.h"
#include "add.h"
#include "clear.h"
int main()
{
    system base[100];
    int num = 0;
    char name_file[40] = "export.txt";
    name_file;
    int key = 0;
    while (1) {
        key = menu();
        switch (key)
        {
            case 1:
                add(&num, base);
                break;
            case 2:
                clear(&num, base);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error! \n");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

**ЛОГИКУ НЕ ПРОВЕРЯЛ**, просто добивался компилируемости.

Вы извините, но ощущение, что это первая ваша программа, причем книжку вы в руки не брали!...

Comment: Она у меня в main. Посмотрите, я добавил код

Comment: @Владислав компилятор попытался, как смог, разобрать синтаксически некорректный код. Начните с избавления от `&num`, часть проблем может исчезнуть сама.

Comment: @D-side с num мне вроде бы выше помогли, а вот с base не знаю как проблему решить.

Comment: @Владислав добавьте куда-нибудь, в каком виде код теперь и какие ошибки выводит компилятор (и, пожалуйста, текстом, а не скриншотами).

Comment: Вот ссылка на код - https://yadi.sk/d/2_edazr03JXSBb.

Comment: См. обновленный ответ

Comment: @Harry выдает по диной ошибке в clear.h и add.h, жалуется на system. Ошибка прикрепил

Comment: Перестаньте исправлять вопрос - получается, что мы все тут пытаемся отвечать не пойми на что...

Comment: Вы исправили `main.h` точно так, как я написал?

Comment: @Harry, разобрался
Проблема была в том, что в main.c первым не подключил main.h

Answer (score 2):

Слово `new` - ключевое слово в C++. Выберите другое имя для этой переменной.

Comment: Это СИ
Я поменял, все равно выводит ошибки

Comment: Возможно, где-то опечатка.

Comment: Даже если это си и `new` там нет, всё равно надо выбору имён уделить внимание. Если в магазине спросиить - заверните мне новое, то вряд ли кто поймёт, что вы хотите.